# Surjective, Injective, Bijective, or Nothing?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Given a mapping from the integers from 1 to N to the integers from 1 to N, determine if the mapping is surjective, injective, bijective, or nothing.

You may choose any character/digit for the four outputs.

## Specs

Input format: `n, arrays of pairs` (`n` is the highest number in the domain and range)

For example, if the first number is `3`, then both the domain and the co-domain are `{1,2,3}`.

For example, `{i+1 | i from 1 to 9}` (n=10) is represented by `10, [[1,2],[2,3],...,[9,10]]`.

The input **may** contain duplicate.

## Testcases

```
2, [[1,2],[2,1]] => bijective
2, [[1,1],[1,2]] => surjective
3, [[1,1]] => injective
3, [[1,2],[2,3]] => injective
4, [[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2]] => nothing
2, [[1,2],[1,2]] => injective
3, [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]] => surjective
2, [[1,1],[1,1],[2,2]] => bijective
```

Comment: Some languages don't have _arrays of pairs_. Can the input be more flexible? Like two arrays for functions' domain and codomain?

Comment: What's the desired result for `2, [[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]`?

Comment: ^^yes, ^nothing

Comment: Do the mappings need to be functions to qualify as bi/in/surjections?

Comment: Why is 4 surjective when the result is only ever 2? Is the mapping really from {1,...,N} to {1,...,N}?

Comment: @David Sorry, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Could you also help me check the other testcases?

Comment: Since the domain and codomain are equal, being injective implies surjective, and vice versa, so you can only have a bijection or nothing. If the sets don't have to be {1,...,N} then it's OK. (e.g. to be surjective but not injective, the domain has to have more elements than the codomain)

Comment: @LeakyNun My case 2 and case -2 returned False, I have looked into it and it seems we have different definitions for "injection". I took the definition from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function which states no "Y" is mapped from more than one "X", and it doesn't state whether "X" can map to more than one "Y". This Math.SE answer also agrees: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1051229/332147 However none of the definitions really stand if your map can have more than one value for each arg right? "Injective" is rly just "one-to" and func is "to-one"  so that "inj func"="1to1"

Comment: Injective means that the preimage of an element in the codomain is a unique element in the domain, or that one input has at most one output. Surjective means that every possible output has at least one input, or that the preimage of the codomain is a subset of the domain. Bijective means both properties are satisfied. Function doesn't necessarily have any special meaning (it sometimes does), and in this case the question asks about mappings anyway.

Comment: From wiki, "In other words, every element of the function's codomain is the image of at most one element of its domain," which means each *output* has at most one *input* instead of what you said above that each *input* has at most one *output*.

Comment: _function means surjective_ No it doesn't. There are functions that are not surjective. I'm not sure it makes sense to define "surjective" for mappings that are not functions. Perhaps you should restrict the challenge to functions. This also confuses me: _n is the highest number in the domain and range_. For the third example, `3, [[1,1]]`, does that mean the domain is `1 2 3` (then the mapping is not a function)? Or that the codomain is `1 2 3`? Or both? I think the rules should be made clearer

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry, could you help me check the testcases?

Comment: What confuses me is that fact that you can have the first input exceeding the number of pairs, or a first-element repeated in two differnet pairs. Any of those implies the mapping is not a function, and I think "injective" or "surjective" only make sense for functions. So perhaps you should restrict the input to be a function. That means each element in the domain has one and only one image element in the codomain

Comment: @LuisMendo Please edit my question as you see fit.

Comment: @LeakyNun But that would imply a big change: removing cases; restricting the input to be functions only; which would make the first number redudant (and so an optional input). It would affect the two current answers. Perhaps contact with the two answerers first

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 13 bytes

```
im&{IdqSQSdE2
```

Takes domain and codomain separately as allowed by comments in OP.

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=im%26%7BIdqSQSdE2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+1%5D%5D%0A2%0A%5B%5B1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+2%5D%5D%0A3%0A%5B%5B1%5D%2C+%5B1%5D%5D%0A3%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+3%5D%5D%0A4%0A%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%5D%5D%0A2%0A%5B%5B1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+2%5D%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

Comment: It does not work...

Comment: @LeakyNun, but, but it gives the right answers?

Comment: You did not account for duplicates

Comment: @LeakyNun what about now?

Comment: Looks like I've confused the definition of surjectivity... consider changing your answer?

Comment: Also, I've clarified the treatment of duplicates in the testcases.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
+!-SQJeC{E*2{IJ
```

The output is identified by:

```
nothing   : 0
surjective: 1
injective : 2
bijective : 3
```

In pseudocode,

```
                  Q=input()                 # pre-initialized var, 'n'
+                 sum(                      # sur=1,in=2,thus bi=sur+in=3,no=0
 !                  not(                    # if 'filtrate'=[], true/surjective
  -SQ                 filter(range(1,Q),    # filter codomain by range
     JeC{E              J=transpose(deduplicate(input()))[-1]
                    ))  # find the "redundant" range, may corrspnd to diffrnt args
 *2{IJ              2*invariant(J,deduplicate)
                  ) # if J(redundnt range) invariant undr dduplicatn, true/injectiv
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=q%2B%21-SQJeC%7BE%2A2%7BIJE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B2%2C1%5D%5D%0A3%0A2%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%5D%5D%0A1%0A3%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%5D%0A2%0A3%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%5D%5D%0A2%0A4%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B2%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C2%5D%2C%5B4%2C2%5D%5D%0A0%0A2%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%5D%5D%0A2%0A3%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B1%2C3%5D%5D%0A1%0A2%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B2%2C2%5D%5D%0A3&debug=0&input_size=3)

Currently, the test suite returns two False's, namely for case 2 and case -2 (second-to-last). This has to do with the definition of "injective", and will be discussed with the OP.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>85</s> 82 bytes

The methodology here is basically:

- Remove duplicate points
- Check if the cardinality of the image of the domain + cardinality of domain is equal to twice the number of points

  - If true -> injective -> return 1
- Check if the cardinality of the image of the domain is equal to the cardinality of the codomain

  - If true -> surjective -> return 2
- If both true -> bijective -> return 3
- If neither -> nothing -> return 0

```py
def f(n,t):l=len;d,c=zip(*set(t));x=l(set(c));return(x+l(set(d))==l(c)*2)+(x==n)*2
```

---

### Test Cases

```py
print(f(2, [(1,2),(2,1)])==3)# => bijective
print(f(2, [(1,1),(1,2)])==2)# => surjective
print(f(3, [(1,1)])==1)# => injective
print(f(3, [(1,2),(2,3)])==1)# => injective
print(f(4, [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2)])==0)# => nothing
print(f(2, [(1,2),(1,2)])==1)# => injective
print(f(3, [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)])==2)# => surjective
print(f(2, [(1,1),(1,1),(2,2)])==3)# => bijective
```

---

**Update**

- **-3** [16-05-26] Multiplied by 2 instead of adding